# iPhone 6 and iPad Air Simulators Not Making Network Calls

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I am trying out Xcode 6 GM Seed and compiling my app that makes use of network calls.  Everything works fine with the network calls when using the Xcode 6 simulators for iPhone 5 or iPad Retina, but oddly the calls are not working when using iPhone 6/plus or iPad Air.  I have tried compiling under iOs 7.1 as well as 8.  If it didn't work under Xcode 6 or ios 8 for all that would be one thing, but I don't understand why something like this doesn't work just under those simulators.  The code is below but as a note I can see that no network call is being made and there is no error thrown.

Update: It is also hapenning under the sim for the 5s.  But not the 5 or earlier and not the non air iPads.

```
-(void)getActiveChannels
{
    NSString *externalURL = @"https://www.mywebservice.com";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:externalURL]];

    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *postDataStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth=%s",AUTH_CODE];

    NSData *requestBodyData = [postDataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestBodyData];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    [postDataTask setTaskDescription:@"getActiveChannels"];

    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

From the break points I tried this is fully executing but as mentioined it never actually makes the call out to the URL when using theiPhone 6 sim or iPad Air.

Here are the methods that make use of returned data although again it isn't getting that far.

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    self.channelDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"%@",task.taskDescription);

    if ([task.taskDescription isEqualToString:@"getActiveChannels"])
    {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"channelsReady"
                                                            object:self.channelDict];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer but not the reason.  Both `NSURLSessionConfiguration` and `NSURLSession` were nil.  I had both set as "weak" as when they were "strong" there were leaks.  Why this is not an issue in some iphone sims but is in others is a mystery to me.